# Is there a way to disable automatic brace completion in Atmel Studio 6?

Tags: atmel-studio

My apologies for a "barely on topic" question, but if any community knows, it should be this one.

I've been using Atmel Studio 6.1 (6.1.2562) for a few weeks now for AVR and ARM development. I'm very experienced with Visual Studio 2010, so it's not unfamiliar territory.

However, the automatic brace completion in Atmel Studio is driving me crazy and I can't find any option to disable it.

Is there some option to disable automatic brace completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded it to take a look and found it under the menu item `VAssistX | Visual Assist X Options` - just disable the circled checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea what `VAssistX` was; in VS these options are elsewhere. Nice find, thank you!

Comment: @JYelton That's the point. Visual Assist X is plug-in for Visual Studio which greatly enhances code completion and refactoring capabilities, especially in older versions of VS. It's a separate product made by a different and not part of Visual Studio, but is very popular.

Comment: @AndrejaKo While it may be great for some, it feels like a kludge for me, coming from a VS2010 + ReSharper setup. :)

Comment: This send me in the right direction. With the newer versions, now called Microchip studio, the brace autocompletion option is now in the section "Editor" instead of "Corrections"